# Trailing shadows in Shadow Map

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have created the shadow map. However it has two problems : 
1. The shadow comes into picture only when I change the model matrix. i.e initially there is no shadows, but when i press a key to move the figure, that is there is a change in the model matrix, the shadow appears.
2. There is a trail of old renders on the texture on the framebuffer that results in a long trail.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

THis is the screenshot of the problem 
[image]

Edit Code here :

```
void generateShadowTex()
{
        //Calculate final ligting properties
    glm::vec4 a_f=light_ambient*mat_ambient;
    glm::vec4 d_f=light_diffuse*mat_diffuse;
    glm::vec4 s_f=light_specular*mat_specular;
    int counter=0;
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);    // need depth test to correctly draw 3D objects 
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1); 
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    if(wframe)
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE); 
    else
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL); 

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,depthTex);

        // MAths here for mvp manupulation 
        //Draw Elements
        if(a<17 || a==18)
            glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, masterNumberIndices[a], GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (char*) NULL+0);
        else
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, masterNumberIndices[a], GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (char*) NULL+0);

        glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(0);

    }
    glUseProgram(0);  

}

void Init_FBO() 
{ 
    GLfloat border[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};  

    //glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
    glGenTextures(1, &depthTex);  
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTex);  
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24,900,900, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);  
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);  
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);  
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);  
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);  
    glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, border);  
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE);  
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LESS);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0); 

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &shadowFBO);  
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, shadowFBO);  
    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);  
    glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);  
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTex, 0);  
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); // go back to the default framebuffer  
    // check FBO status 
    GLenum FBOstatus = glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER); 
    if(FBOstatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) 
    {
        printf("GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE failed, CANNOT use FBO\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Frame Buffer Done Succesfully\n");
    } 
}


void display() 
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, shadowFBO); 
    generateShadowTex(); 
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); 
    generateScene(); 
}
```

Comment: Obviously you have done some math wrong at some stage, though I'm not sure how you think we can help without seeing your code.

Comment: @Tim: FYI: if someone hasn't provided sufficient information to answer it, then you should vote to close their question as "Not a Real Question."

Comment: @Tim : I have edited the question to add relevant sections of the code.....

Comment: @NicolBolas : I wasnt sure what kind of information would be asked hence I thought that i would paste it as required. That was stupid of me. I have furnished information that I think may perhaps help

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the depth buffer before you clear it. From the OpenGL specification:

> If a buffer is not present, then a glClear directed at that buffer has no effect. [1](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClear.xml)

And:

> **GL_DEPTH_TEST**
>
> If enabled, do depth comparisons and update the depth buffer. Note that even if the depth buffer exists and the depth mask is non-zero, the depth buffer is not updated if the depth test is disabled. [2](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnable.xml)

As to the first part of your question, I can only guess what the problem might be, but you're probably not initializing the model matrix correctly.